# MDPI Default Template Highlight

Tags: overleaf, highlighting, soul, mdpi

Hi everyone I am working on MDPI submission using their template avaliable on [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/mdpi-article-template/fcpwsspfzsph) and [their site here](https://www.mdpi.com/data/MDPI_template.zip?v=20210406) I am highlighting changes using the soul package and the `\hl{}` but everytime I do this on the abstract Overleaf seems to freeze on compiling and I get no answear. The log files complain of something like:

`Use of \SOUL@n doesn't match its definition.`

I believe it has to do to the fact that the template defines the abstract as a macro, but I am not sure. Would be helpful some form of highlighting text not using `\hl{}`. The `mbox`is a problem because of line breaking, `\textcolor{}` works but it is not the same effect.

It is a big class and template file to include here, but the part that generates the error is located at line 106 if you add `\hl{}` to some part of the text. Like this:

```
...

\abstract{A single paragraph \hl{of about 200 words maximum. 
For research articles, abstracts should give a pertinent overview of the 
work. We strongly encourage authors} to use the following style of 
structured abstracts, but without headings: (1) Background: place the 
question addressed in a broad context and highlight the purpose of the 
study; (2) Methods: describe briefly the main methods or treatments 
applied; (3) Results: summarize the article's main findings; (4) 
Conclusion: indicate the main conclusions or interpretations. The abstract 
should be an objective representation of the article, it must not contain 
results which are not presented and substantiated in the main text and 
should not exaggerate the main conclusions.}

...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you provide a bit more information, by adding the code for a small document that generates this error? It is preferred that you add the code directly to your question (and not link to external websites), that way the question is self-contained and remains useful in case the link changes.

Comment: Could not add the complete file available on the link, edited to add a snippet, hope this helps.

Comment: I think the issue is that id does not work in the abstract. This is the same for items that come from the Soul package.

Comment: I don't know how, but `\usepackage{siunitx}` fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `\usepackage{siunitx}` suggested by Andrey L. also fixed the problem here. `\hl{}` works just fine in abstract section of the mdpi template.